# I applied viewpager to this page when i swipe page from this to another i got Exception

Tags: android

I applied viewpager to this page when i swipe page from this to another i got Exception:

> Exception is "The specified child already has a parent. You must call
>   `removeView()` on the child's parent first"

How Can i Solve that Can any one of you please let me know Here is my Code with Bug Console.

```
public class FamilyCosts extends Fragment
{

   TextView user_one,user_two,user_three;

   FragmentManager fManager;

   FragmentTransaction tx;
   @Nullable
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      final View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_familycosts,container,false);
      fManager=getActivity().getFragmentManager();
      user_one=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.user_one);
      user_two=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.user_two);
      user_three=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.user_three);

      user_one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          tx=fManager.beginTransaction();
          tx.replace(R.id.fragment, new Jeff());
          tx.commit();
        }
      });
      user_two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            tx=fManager.beginTransaction();
            tx.replace(R.id.fragment, new Harriet());
            tx.commit(); 
         }
      });
      user_three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             tx=fManager.beginTransaction();
             tx.replace(R.id.fragment, new George());
           /*tx.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            tx.addToBackStack(null);*/
            tx.commit();
        }
    });
    return v; }}
```

[Error Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xNpl.png)

[image]